# Canning Chili Sauce

Tags: canning, chili

I'm going to have a *very* large crop of Thai chilis this year.  I'd like to make a large batch of sweet chili sauce.  Can this be canned like you would jelly or jam so that it's shelf stable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, provided that it has sufficient salt and/or acid content, which is fairly easy for a chili sauce.  The Ball Jar Company [even has a recipe for it](https://www.freshpreserving.com/thai-dipping-sauce-%7C-thai-sauce-recipe---ball-fresh-preserving-br1059.html).  You could also [turn it into a jelly](https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2012/08/thai-sweet-chili-jelly-recipe.html) and store it.

Comment: Important nitpick: the salt in contemporary canning recipes is not a factor in preservation (unlike pickling recipes). What you need is sufficient acid. Best to follow tested recipes, such as those you linked.

Comment: rumtscho: I was thinking of Samal Oelek, or chili crunch, both of which are primarily preserved by salt (they have a lot).